# Ассемблер. Помогите поправить код

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

[image: написать выражение в ассемблер]Помогите поправить код

```
{mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov ax, A
sub ax, B
cwd 
mov ax, D
mul D
div D
add ax, D
mul ax
sub ax, 26890
mov Result, ax}
```

Comment: Именно для указанных значений? `mov eax, -26562   mov Result,eax`

Comment: В этом выражении нужно делить два раза. a/d^2 и b/d^2. Как это записать в коде?

Comment: Вы когда делаете a-b то у вас результат остается в ax, вы делаете cwd, знак уходит в dx, но основной результат все равно в ax, который вы тут же благополучно затираете положив в него D

Comment: `gcc -S -Os t.c` сделает ассемблерный код в файле t.s. Уровень опимизации по экономии памяти `-Os` создает (imho) наиболее понятный для человека код.  Берете и смотрите

Comment: Последний код не работает...

Comment: У вас условие в заголовке не совпадает с условием на картинке

Comment: Отредактировала заголовок

Comment: Ещё Вы не указали какую арифметику использовать - целочисленная или с плавающей точкой? И какой результат на выходе - целочисленный?

Comment: A=2345, B=-13131, D=10.

Comment: @user538324 Эти входные данные ясны, но ведь A/D^2 = 2345/100 = 23.45 Так вот и вопрос  какую арифметику использовать - целочисленная или с плавающей точкой? И какой результат на выходе?

Comment: В условиях не сказано... Но в итоге, в  ответе должен быть результат от 1го до 5ти

Comment: Получается '6' - больше 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант реализации:

```
proc2   proc    A: word, B: word, D: word
    ; x=(d+(a/d^2)-(b/d^2))^2-26890 для A=2345,B=-13131,D=10

    mov     ax, D
    mov     bx, ax

    imul    ax      ; ax = D^2
    mov     cx, ax  ; cx = D^2

    mov     ax, A
    mov     dx, B
    sub     ax, dx  ; ax = A - B
    xor     dx, dx
    div     cx  ; dx:ax / cx
                ; ax = (A-B)/D^2
    
    add     ax, bx      ; ax = D + (A-B)/D^2
    imul    ax          ; dx:ax = (D + (A-B)/D^2)^2
    sub     ax, 26890   ; ax = (D + (A-B)/D^2)^2 - 26890
    mov     result, ax
    ret
    endp
```

Результат: число 6 (шесть)

Answer (score -1):

```
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 2345
mov bx, -13131
add ax, bx
mov dx, 0
mov bx, 10
div bx
mov cx, ax
mov ax, 2345
mov bx, 10
mul bx
div bx
add ax, cx
mul ax, 2
sub ax, 26890
mov Result, ax
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: У вас решение для условия в заголовке, а не в тексте вопроса. А они разные.

Comment: Отредактировала заголовок